Why is flexible 1/2" tubing sticking out of our sink drain cleanout?
There's a 5 inch piece of half-inch clear plastic tubing coming out of the drain cleanout under our kitchen sink. We've been in the house for 3 years and never really thought much of it, but recently we've noticed water dripping out of the tube. I assume that's telling us that the drain is slow and starting to backup. What I'm curious about is if that tube was put there as an early warning of a clogged drain, in which case maybe it is a nice feature, or is it best to replace it with a regular closed cleanout plug?


A backup would pour out of that tube, not drip. Was there ever an appliance or other device there that would've drained through that tube?

that looks like a hack that someone dreamed up

The jokes write themselves.  :O

But on the serious side, isherwood is probably right, or if not I'll guess it's a hacky snaking adapter.  Perhaps the drain needed frequent snaking and the owner didn't have the right tools or the motivation to fix the underlying problem.

the tube probably emits sewer gasses
